Drivers for AMD FirePro D700 in Ubuntu 24
I've got an old Mac Pro 6,1 at home running Ubuntu 24. Its got a pair of AMD FirePro D700's inside (The Apple exclusive GPU ones). I've tried installing AMD drivers for it but Ubuntu still says its using software rendering not hardware rendering. I'm not sure if the current AMD drivers support the D700s. Does anyone know if there are drivers for these available?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204014/amd-firepro-amdgpu-pro-drivers-on-18-04-and-opencl
